# will email attachement get saved in our server too..?

Tags: email-attachments, php

I want to develop a php script to send emails but I wanted to know whether adding attachment/s to the email would eat up my server space or will it get transferred from my server to the recipients server.. Please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message, with attachments, will be passed to the recipient's server. It will only take up space on your server if you choose to store a copy.

Comment: Thanks Mike, but by default will it get stored ?

Comment: I have no idea - I know nothing about your mail system.

Comment: I am using the default cpanel mail system provided by my provider.

Comment: 'By default' has no meaning: mail servers do what you tell them. I doubt an ISP will store outbound mail - they don't have the disk space. If you think your ISP's mail server is likely to store your outbound mail you need to talk to them about it.